# How to pass a context.read to children widgets in Flutter? Potential BuildContext error issue

Tags: flutter, dart

### Background

I am trying to create a refresh button that floats on the right side of the screen that will refresh a listview

### My Code

I am using the following class that will pull JSON data and create a listview for me via `context.read<ThreadData>().fetchData;` on first load.

```
class OpenThread extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    context.read<ThreadData>().fetchData;
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(...)
        body: (...)
              child: 
              IconButton(onPressed: () {
              debugPrint('Pressed');
              context.read<ThreadData>().fetchData;
              }, icon: Icon(Icons.refresh))
            );
   }
}
```

In there is a reload button `IconButton()` which when pressed is perfectly reloading my data `onPressed: () { debugPrint('Pressed'); context.read<ThreadData>().fetchData; }`

### My Problem

However, I've created a child widget called `ThreadPageNav` which I've added as a child to my body in the above `OpenThread` class as follows

```
        Stack(
          children: [
            Container(...)
            ThreadPageNav(),
```

The `ThreadPageNav()` widget looks like this

```
class ThreadPageNav extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return
      Positioned( ... 
         child:
              IconButton(onPressed: () {
              debugPrint('Pressed');
              context.read<ThreadData>().fetchData;
              }, icon: Icon(Icons.refresh))
      );


      }
  }
```

**However, here the `context.read<ThreadData>().fetchData;` call doesn't work at all**

I immediately get an error: `The method 'read' isn't defined for the type 'BuildContext'.`

### In case it matters

Just in case it matters, the OpenThread and ThreadData are originally setup from a navigator push, with `ThreadData` doing the JSON request and data collection and `OpenThread` creating the listview and styles and displaying it on the screen as follows:

```
        Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                    create: (context) => ThreadData(
                        tVars: ThreadVars(
                            threadid: map['threadid'],
                            threadtitle: map['title'])
                          ),
                    builder: (context, child)
                      {
                      return OpenThread(
                                  tVars: ThreadVars(
                                            threadid: map['threadid'],
                                            threadtitle: map['title'])
                                    );
                      },
                    ),
                )
          );
```

Comment: seems that your code does not include [ReadContext](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ReadContext.html) extension

Comment: @pskink Yes!  Thank you!  Problem solved

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @pskink nailed it above in the comments

I'm leaving this here just incase someone else stumbles on this problem and needs a solution

The answer is that I didn't include the [ReadContext](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ReadContext.html) extension

All I had to do was add `import 'package:provider/provider.dart';` at the top of my .dart file and it works perfectly